# animated gifs synced with jquery slider

Tags: jquery, animated-gif

First and foremost I am a beginner in coding both javascript and jquery so bear with me as I try and articulate concepts that are still alien to me.

I am trying to figure out how to place an animated gif that combines 2 gifs together to sync with a jquery text slider so that as the second part of the animated gif renders text (tips & tricks) will fade in or slide in?

How do I position the animated gif to appear left aligned to the slider?

So far I have looked at simpleslider and bxslider and well I'm probably overlooking the answer so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How do I position the animated gif to appear left aligned to the slider?"

```
<img src="youanimatedgif.gif" class"left" />
<div id="yourSlider" class="right" ></div>
```

then in your css

```
.left{
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  }

.right{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

setting display to inline-block will make the two elements side by side

Comment: For the image source is there supposed to be class="left" ?
Also if I have 2 css file do I just list them one after the other like so?
<link type="text/css" href="sitename/jshowoff.css">
<link type="text/css" href="sitename/gif_align_test.css">
or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: you can list them one after another with no problem , they both need to the in the <head> tag  , in my example you would have class left on the element you want on the left , and right for the one on the right